# iOs: at Launch, segue to a specified viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am hoping for a quick tip or strategy on this problem and see how you have or would solve this.

At launch, I am checking for the user "status." This basically means:
1. Check if they have a session in progress aka.. they are logged in 
2. Check if they have entered in a Credit Card yet
3. Check if they have clicked on a confirmation email

Based on whether these statuses are true or not, I want to segue at launch to the appropriate viewcontroller (ex: if no CC detected, segue to a credit card entry page ... etc).

Currently, my iOS8 setup is as follows:
1. Checking user "status" in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in the appdelegate
2. I have a launch screen xib that (as far as I know) cannot have a viewcontroller attached (therefore I cannot segue at that point which would be most ideal).

Does anyone know a way to tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are using a storyboard. That's part of the problem here, but it is not insuperable. By the time your code in `didFinishLaunching...` runs, you already have a window and that window has a root view controller. Thus you can get a reference to that root view controller and do any pushing or presenting of a different view controller on top of it. And since you are doing this before the interface is shown, your interface will appear with the desired view controller showing.

But be careful not to do anything time-consuming. I don't know what all this "checking" involves but if it takes any time, the watchdog will kill your app dead for taking too long to launch. It is better to launch into your root view controller and *then* do your checking - even if this means the user will see the root view controller for a while. Just design a root view controller that is okay to show.

Comment: thanks matt, I followed your advice and went with launching into root and then checking. It went swimmingly!